# android current location compare other locations and return nearest location

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, location

I use GPSTracker class to get current location and my activity class to compare current location with other 4 market location then it should return nearest market. When i want to open this activity from another activity, i got error unfotunately stopped..

Here my code; GPSTracker class:

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final Context mContext;

// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude

// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            // First get location from Network Provider
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}

/**
 * Stop using GPS listener
 * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
 * */
public void stopUsingGPS(){
    if(locationManager != null){
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }       
}

/**
 * Function to get latitude
 * */
public double getLatitude(){
    if(location != null){
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}

/**
 * Function to get longitude
 * */
public double getLongitude(){
    if(location != null){
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}

/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
 * @return boolean
 * */
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog
 * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
 * */
public void showSettingsAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

}
```

Here my activity class:

```
public class ShoppingEnd extends Activity {

    double [] distances;
    double distanceToLemar, distanceToGulen, distanceToKas, distanceToSerin;


    GPSTracker gps;
    TextView cheapText, nearText;

        Location currentLoc;
        Location LemarLoc, GulenLoc , KasLoc , SerinLoc;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.shop_end);

        cheapText =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.cheapest);
        nearText =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.nearest);


        nearText.setText(recommendByDistance());

    }

    private String recommendByDistance()
    {
        getCurrentLocation();
        getMarketLocations();
        calculateDistances();

        Log.d("nearestt", getNearestMarket());
        return getNearestMarket();
    }

    private void getCurrentLocation()
    {
         gps = new GPSTracker(ShoppingEnd.this);
         if (gps.canGetLocation())
         {
             double lat = gps.getLatitude();
             double lng = gps.getLongitude();

             currentLoc.setLatitude(lat);
             currentLoc.setLongitude(lng);

         } 
         else 
         {
             gps.showSettingsAlert();        
         }
    }

    private void getMarketLocations()
    {
        double lemar_lat = 35.2478209 , lemar_lng = 33.0236201;
        LemarLoc.setLatitude(lemar_lat);
            LemarLoc.setLongitude(lemar_lng);

            double gulen_lat = 35.2456597 , gulen_lng = 33.0352375;
            GulenLoc.setLatitude(gulen_lat);
            GulenLoc.setLongitude(gulen_lng);

            double kas_lat = 35.2454282 , kas_lng = 33.0360717;
            KasLoc.setLatitude(kas_lat);
            KasLoc.setLongitude(kas_lng);

            double serin_lat = 35.2456885 , serin_lng = 33.0360405;
            SerinLoc.setLatitude(serin_lat);
            SerinLoc.setLongitude(serin_lng);
    }

    private void calculateDistances()
    {
        distanceToLemar = currentLoc.distanceTo(LemarLoc);
        distances[0] = distanceToLemar;

            distanceToGulen = currentLoc.distanceTo(GulenLoc);
        distances[1] = distanceToGulen;

            distanceToKas = currentLoc.distanceTo(KasLoc);
        distances[2] = distanceToKas;

            distanceToSerin = currentLoc.distanceTo(SerinLoc);
            distances[3] = distanceToSerin;
    }

    private String getNearestMarket()
    {

        Arrays.sort(distances);
        if(distances[0]==distanceToLemar)
            return "Lemar";
        else if(distances[0]==distanceToGulen)
            return "Gulen";
        else if(distances[0]==distanceToKas)
            return "Kas";
        else
            return "Serin";
    }

}
```

Here logcat:

```
04-28 18:47:35.274: E/AndroidRuntime(6771): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-28 18:47:35.274: E/AndroidRuntime(6771): Process: com.ssa, PID: 6771
04-28 18:47:35.274: E/AndroidRuntime(6771): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ssa/com.ssa.ShoppingEnd}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-28 18:47:35.274: E/AndroidRuntime(6771):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2215)
04-28 18:47:35.274: E/AndroidRuntime(6771):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
04-28 18:47:35.274: E/AndroidRuntime(6771):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
04-28 18:47:35.274: E/AndroidRuntime(6771):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
04-28 18:47:35.274: E/AndroidRuntime(6771):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-28 18:47:35.274: E/AndroidRuntime(6771):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-28 18:47:35.274: E/AndroidRuntime(6771):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
04-28 18:47:35.274: E/AndroidRuntime(6771):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-28 18:47:35.274: E/AndroidRuntime(6771):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-28 18:47:35.274: E/AndroidRuntime(6771):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:781)
04-28 18:47:35.274: E/AndroidRuntime(6771):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-28 18:47:35.274: E/AndroidRuntime(6771):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-28 18:47:35.274: E/AndroidRuntime(6771): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-28 18:47:35.274: E/AndroidRuntime(6771):     at com.ssa.ShoppingEnd.getMarketLocations(ShoppingEnd.java:69)
04-28 18:47:35.274: E/AndroidRuntime(6771):     at com.ssa.ShoppingEnd.recommendByDistance(ShoppingEnd.java:41)
04-28 18:47:35.274: E/AndroidRuntime(6771):     at com.ssa.ShoppingEnd.onCreate(ShoppingEnd.java:32)
04-28 18:47:35.274: E/AndroidRuntime(6771):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
04-28 18:47:35.274: E/AndroidRuntime(6771):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-28 18:47:35.274: E/AndroidRuntime(6771):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
04-28 18:47:35.274: E/AndroidRuntime(6771):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: You never initialize any of the locations you are accessing. They will be null when you try to access them which is causing your crash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never initialize your Location variables, so they are null when you call setLatitude on the first one. Thus, NullPointerException.

It's also convention to only start class names with a capital letter. Variables should be camel case, starting with a lower case letter:

```
Location lemarLoc = new Location("");
```

Comment: I initialized all like currentLoc = new Location(currentLoc); , lemarLoc = new Location(lemarLoc); etc..  however crash still stays same:(

Comment: That just copies the location from the argument you pass to the constructor, so you're trying to initialize it by copying from something that's null. Initialize them with an empty string argument like in my code snippet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However second reason of main problem is array. I delete array and do distance comparison with if/elses, then it runs correctly. I still dont know why array cause null pointer exp. ? (also tried with array and other's initializing staff) Anyway, thanks again..